# How to count lines within polygons?

Tags: count, polyline, qgis, polygons

I would like to count the amount of lines within polygons.

The questions I would like to answer are:
How many lines are within each polygon (enveloped AND intersecting)?
How long is each line within each polygon OR how long are all the lines (combined) within each polygon?

I am using `QGIS 2.18.12` (do not know how to write code)

[image: Visualization of question and desired result]

Comment: I found one possible solution but unfortunately it does not seem to do the trick for me.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237889/qgis-count-lines-in-polygon-to-be-part-of-a-graphical-model/237891

Answer (score 0):

first calculate all lines lenght,

second use Select By Location proccess (intersect etc.),

last one is Statistics By Categories proccess.